# Marketing Cloud - Multi-Org & One Click Unsubscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud, multi-org

I am about to turn on Multi-org in our marketing cloud instance in order to connect to another sales cloud org.

Currently in Marketing cloud we use One Click Unsubscribes for our email sends, which unsubscribe contacts from All Subscribers or a publication list.

When we enable Multi-org will one click unsubscribe be affected? I have read in the documentation that standard profile centers do not work with Multi-org, but does this also allow to the one-click unsubscribe functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Multi Org does not mean that you can connect one MC BU to several SC Orgs.

Comment: Actually..that is exactly what it means. Multi-Org allows  to connect a different Sales Cloud org for each MC business unit.

Comment: @Rain as you say for EACH MC business unit. Not several Orgs for one business unit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on how your business units are set up.

If you are sending email from your BU and someone uses one-click unsubscribe, they will be unsubscribed at the list level. If they click "unsubscribe from all" they will be unsubscribed at whatever level you dictate for that particular BU, whether it's recorded only at that BU or if it's shared with the Enterprise.

If you're sending mail from your Enterprise and someone uses one-click unsubscribe they're still unsubscribed at the list level, but "unsubscribe from all" unsubscribes you at the enterprise level, affecting all BUs.